# How do I allow a button click to fire on a form that fails validation?

Tags: c#, winforms

I added validation to a textbox on a form, this disables all events on the form until the user fixes the text.  But I still want them to be able to execute the Close() method which is assigned to a button.

```
    private void newCategory_textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string error = null;

        if (this.newCategory_textBox.Text.Contains(':'))
        {
            error = "An invalid character is present in the category";
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        category_errorProvider.SetError((Control)sender, error);
    }
```

This event becomes disabled, but I want to enable it even though validation failed

```
    private void cancelCategories_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking

Comment: @Bigiansen when validation fails, it disables the button click, but I want it enabled because it controls the form closing.

Comment: Then disable the validation and handle it manually perhaps?